# How can I restart container using healthcheck in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How can I restart docker container of server when curl failed to call API?
I prepared such docker-compose.yml file.

```
server:   
  build: server
  command:
    - run
  healthcheck:
    test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://localhost/ && echo 'cool, it works'"]
    interval: 5s
    timeout: 5s
    retries: 3
```

Thanks!!!!!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64041910/180258 on how this can be achieved somewhat hackily, with curl's own retry mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Healthcheck's are only displayed by the docker engine, there's no included way to handle a failing healthcheck at that level. You can run something outside of the engine to check the healthcheck's and do the restart.

However the best option is to switch to swarm mode running the container which is healthcheck aware and will restart containers with failing healthcheck's for you.