# Restarting an unhealthy docker container based on healthcheck

Tags: docker, health-monitoring

I am using `Docker version 17.09.0-ce`, and I see that containers are marked as unhealthy. Is there an option to get the container restart instead of keeping the container as unhealthy?

Comment: I think that would happens when you launch it in docker swarm mode and run it as a service and not for a normal docker container

Comment: I am not using swarm or any orchestration tools for some specific reasons.

Comment: Then you can use another script using `docker events -f event=health_status` (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events/#extended-description) and then take action based on health of the container

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Restarting of unhealty container feature was in the original PR (https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/22719), but was removed after a discussion and considered to be done later as enhancement of RestartPolicy.

At this moment you can use this workaround to automatically restarting unhealty containers: https://hub.docker.com/r/willfarrell/autoheal/

Here is a sample compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  autoheal:
    restart: always
    image: willfarrell/autoheal
    environment:
      - AUTOHEAL_CONTAINER_LABEL=all
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Simply execute `docker-compose up -d` on this

Comment: Won't this make it so you can't specify your own image name? Also is the environment or volume necessary? The volume doesn't seem relevant. Can you use this image as a dependency?

Comment: @obesechicken13 the volume is so that the docker socket is available to the running container internally

Comment: which poses a huge security risk https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17983623

Comment: There is still an open feature request: [trigger restart from unhealthy status](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/28400)

Comment: @InsOp So what do you propose? How can this be done without giving the container access to Docker?

Answer (score 51):

You can restart automatically an unhealthy container by setting a smart HEALTHCHECK and a proper restart policy.

The Docker restart policy should be one of `always` or `unless-stopped`.

The HEALTHCHECK instead should implement a logic that kills the container when it's unhealthy.

In the following example I used `curl` with its internal retry mechanism and piped it (in case of failure/service unhealthy) to the `kill` command.

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5m --timeout=2m --start-period=45s \
   CMD curl -f --retry 6 --max-time 5 --retry-delay 10 --retry-max-time 60 "http://localhost:8080/health" || bash -c 'kill -s 15 -1 && (sleep 10; kill -s 9 -1)'
```

The important step to understand here is that the retry logic is self-contained in the `curl` command, the Docker retry here actually is mandatory but useless. Then if the `curl` HTTP request fails 3 times, then `kill` is executed. First it sends a SIGTERM to all the processes in the container, to allow them to gracefully stop, then after 10 seconds it sends a SIGKILL to completely kill all the processes in the container. It must be noted that when the PID1 of a container dies, then the container itself dies and the restart policy is invoked.

- `kill` docs: https://linux.die.net/man/1/kill
- `curl` docs: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html
- `docker` restart docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#restart

Gotchas: `kill` behaves differently in bash than in sh. In bash you can use `-1` to signal all the processes with PID greater than 1 to die.

Comment: cool thanks for the explanation  Let's say the container has already been restarted, but the problem could not be solved... does it not end in an endless loop?

Comment: Yes, it goes into an endless loop. The only way to stop it would be by `docker compose stop` or `docker compose rm -f`.

There is a super convoluted alternative to fix this behavior. Which is: mount the Docker socket inside the container, implement the retry logic in a `.sh` file inside the container, write a counter on a volume so that it's persisted and when the counter is greater than your number of attempts use the docker socket to send a `stop` message to the container itself. :)

Comment: Or: don't rely on the docker restart mechanism and use something as supervisord

Comment: docker healthcheck has `retries` option

Comment: @cdalxndr healthcheck `retries` is for a different purpose than what @naramsim is explaining here in comments.

Comment: @Naramsim as pointed in your Gotchas, -1 signals all processes besides init (PID 1). Hence my container is not dying + no restart. what I'm I missing here? Even if I send TERM or SIGKILL to PID 1 explicitly it will be ignored

Comment: Could be worth adding `--retry-connrefused` as option to the curl command. Otherwise if the server isn't up for some reason curl will fail on first try

Answer (score 17):

Unhealthy docker containers may be restarted with simple crontab rule:

```
* * * * * docker ps -f health=unhealthy --format "docker restart {{.ID}}" | sh
```

Comment: Probably safer to do `docker ps -q -f health=unhealthy | xargs docker restart` rather than invoking a shell.

Comment: Also, for when there's no unhealthy containers use the `-r` or `--no-run-if-empty` flag for xargs, like:
`docker ps -q -f health=unhealthy | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker restart`

Answer (score 13):

You can try put in your Dockerfile something like this:

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --timeout=2s CMD curl --fail http://localhost || kill 1
```

Don't forget `--restart always` option.

`kill 1` will kill process with pid 1 in container and force container exit. Usually the process started by CMD or ENTRYPOINT has pid 1.

Unfortunally, this method likely don't change container's state to unhealthy, so be careful with it.

Comment: Isn't this killing the container at the very first failed curl?

Comment: @Naramsim You right, first curl fail will kill the container, but with --restart always it will be resurrected. Also, as docs say, "The health check will first run interval seconds after the container is started". Therefore increasing interval will prevent first fast failure if container is starting too long.

Comment: I answered to this question with a proper way to restart an unhealthy container.

Answer (score 12):

For standalone containers, Docker does not have native integration to restart the container on health check failure though we can achieve the same using Docker events and a script. Health check is better integrated with Swarm. With health check integrated to Swarm, when a container in a service is unhealthy, Swarm automatically shuts down the unhealthy container and starts a new container to maintain the container count as specified in the replica count of a service.

Answer (score 6):

According to https://codeblog.dotsandbrackets.com/docker-health-check/

Create container and add " restart: always".

In the use of healthcheck, pay attention to the following points:

For standalone containers, Docker does not have native integration to restart the container on health check failure though we can achieve the same using Docker events and a script. Health check is better integrated with Swarm. With health check integrated to Swarm, when a container in a service is unhealthy, Swarm automatically shuts down the unhealthy container and starts a new container to maintain the container count as specified in the replica count of a service.

Comment: Please put all of your answer in the response rather than links.

Comment: I  solved this problem. In the use of healthcheck, pay attention to the following points

For standalone containers, Docker does not have native integration to restart the container on health check failure though we can achieve the same using Docker events and a script. Health check is better integrated with Swarm. With health check integrated to Swarm, when a container in a service is unhealthy, Swarm automatically shuts down the unhealthy container and starts a new container to maintain the container count as specified in the replica count of a service.

Answer (score 5):

Docker has a couple of ways to get details on container health.  You can configure health checks and how often they run. Also, health checks can be run on applications running inside a container, like http (this would use `curl --fail` option.) You can view the `health_status` event to get details.

For detailed information on an unhealthy container the inspect command comes in handy, `docker inspect --format='{{json .State.Health}}' container-name`  (see https://blog.newrelic.com/2016/08/24/docker-health-check-instruction/ for more details.)

You should resolve the error condition causing the "unhealthy" tag (anytime the health check command runs and gets an exit code of 1) first. This may or may not require that Docker restart the container, depending on the error. If you are starting/restarting your [containers automatically](https://www.aquasec.com/wiki/display/containers/Starting+Docker+Containers+Automatically), then either trapping the start errors or logging them and the health check status can help address errors quickly. Check the link if you are interested in auto start.

Comment: If you are on windows you will have to use double quotes, or it won't work: `docker inspect --format="{{json .State.Health}}" name-of-your-container`

Answer (score 0):

```
   unhealthy_container_restarter:
    image: docker:cli
    network_mode: none
    cap_drop:
      - ALL
    volumes: [ "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock" ]
    command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "while true; do sleep 60; docker ps -q -f health=unhealthy | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker restart; done" ]
    restart: unless-stopped
```

`What this does:` each 60 seconds search for unhealthy containers and restart it.

`Why not willfarrell/autoheal`: This is simpler. From first look at compose file I know what it does and more important 'how'. Compose is not dependent on another image that may be maintained or not in future.

`Why not cron`: everything is in one file. It's not dependent from external manual job that need to be made.

#### Alternative

[deunhealth](https://github.com/qdm12/deunhealth)