# Fail to run Postman Remote URL with Docker and Environment File

Tags: docker, postman

I am able to run the postman collection below with environment file from the command line using newman

newman run  https://www.getpostman.com/collections/b9dc5f129194190a8e54 -e Local.postman_environment.json

If I try using docker command below it fails with environment file not found.

docker run -t postman/newman_ubuntu1404 run  https://www.getpostman.com/collections/b9dc5f129194190a8e54 -e Local.postman_environment.json
error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Local.postman_environment.json'

If I run **without** the environment file in the command, the collection is run successfully but suffice to say the environment variables are missing. Presumably something wrong in the way I am sending the command which includes the environment file?

Comment: I had this trouble too and it was so annoying - You may need to specify a volume. I don't like sharing links to work but I managed to do it for this in the end, not sure if some of it might help you https://github.com/DannyDainton/postman-docker

Comment: Thanks Danny. I actually found your notes on postman which shortly after which helped a lot! I very quickly hit another barrier whereby my collection is being run before my web app is ready. Seems to be not uncommon. You may have had it also. Problem is it's not enough to check TCP connection as this does not ensure the app is ready. I'm having a problem in my docker-compose config to call a wait script before running the collection

Comment: Can it use a `depends_on` or something in the compose file?

Comment: depends_on is there. There is the option to use healthchecks which should be simple to add in the app config

Comment: i.e. 
    healthcheck:
       test: ["CMD",  "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8880"]
       interval: 5s
       timeout: 5s
       retries: 5

This actually checks the app is started. Running the curl from cmd line works but the postman collection service returns the error below when it is run from docker-compose

ERROR: for postman_checks  Container "62b3eacdf9ad" is unhealthy

Comment: Anything useful here for that? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47088261/restarting-an-unhealthy-docker-container-based-on-healthcheck

Answer (score 0):

Figured out both problems

In docker-compose.yaml file:

```
 postman_checks:
    container_name: postman_test
    build: .
    image: postman/newman_ubuntu1404
    command:
      run https://www.getpostman.com/collections/12345129194190a8e54
      -e ./postman/Local.postman_environment.json
      -g ./postman/postman_globals.json

healthcheck:
   test: ["CMD",  "curl", "http://127.0.0.1:8680"]
   interval: 25s
   timeout: 5s
   retries: 50
```

The port 8680 in the health check is the internal docker port, not external. It's possible to connect to the container - docker inspect  and look for State.Health

Comment: could you elaborate a little more on how you got it to work? I have a similar problem where it works fine without the container, but in docker it says `could not load environment`.  I have the  -e flag set in my docker-compose.yml https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71167861/postman-docker-compose-can-not-find-env-json-file