# docker compose healthcheck does not exit with error failed to start

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

i have this compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - "./:/src"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://localhost:8080/fail-health-check || exit 1"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 1
    command: ["go", "run", "main.go"]
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.21 as builder

WORKDIR /src

COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
```

When i run the docker compose, the app's healthcheck keeps running. I want the container to exit with error failed to start container.

golang code `main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4/middleware"
)

func main() {
  r := echo.New()
  r.Use(middleware.Logger())
  
  fmt.Println("start http server on port 8080")
  if err := r.Start(":8080"); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
}
```

here the log in app:

```
test_healthcheck_go_app-app-1  | {"time":"2023-11-14T04:08:42.450751594Z","id":"","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","host":"localhost:8080","method":"GET","uri":"/fail-health-check","user_agent":"curl/7.88.1","status":404,"error":"code=404, message=Not Found","latency":26375,"latency_human":"26.375µs","bytes_in":0,"bytes_out":24}
```

`docker ps` output

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                         COMMAND            CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS                    NAMES
ff389f13ab1d   test_healthcheck_go_app-app   "go run main.go"   48 seconds ago   Up 46 seconds (unhealthy)   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   test_healthcheck_go_app-app-1
```

Comment: It looks like your container is receiving the HTTP request and returning HTTP 404, so the `curl` command is running and presumably returns the failure.  Are you asking about [Restarting an unhealthy docker container based on healthcheck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47088261/restarting-an-unhealthy-docker-container-based-on-healthcheck)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the container to exit with error failed to start container.

1. Your application has no idea it's running in a container.
2. Your main process (`go run main.go`) is running as `PID 1`, which you need to stop to exit the container and which is protected.

Knowing these two facts, you have a few possibilities:

1. Install docker cli inside the container. Then map your docker socket into your container and run `docker stop`. Mapping the socket into the container implies security issues -- proceed carefully.
2. Run something like `ps -afx | grep go | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -9` (kudos to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54594847/3324556)), i.e. specifically in your `healthcheck` it might look like `curl -f http://localhost:8080/fail-health-check || (ps -afx | grep go | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -9)`
3. But what you're really looking for, in my opinion, is a container orchestration system, like Kubernetes. This might be an overkill to advise, might be not. Depending on what you're planning with your project. In any case it will help you manage your running containers more robustly.

If you want to produce an error, it depends on which log driver you're using. Using `syslog` driver, the Docker container writes logs to `/var/log/syslog`. So before exiting you might want to `echo "Error text"` to `/var/log/syslog`.